includepdf doesn't find all the files in the folder
I want to use includepdf to include several .pdf files in my latex text. I am using \usepackage{pdfpages} and when I call the first file using: \includepdf[pages=-,pagecommand={},width=1\textwidth]{Article_1.pdf} everything works fine, the file contains everything and looks as expected. However, for the files (I have some more pdf files) after that, for example if I call \includepdf[pages=-,pagecommand={},width=\textwidth]{Article_1_SM.pdf} I get the error: Package pdfpages Error: Cannot find file Article_1_SM.pdf.. However all the files are in the same folder and I call the second command right after the first. Even if I switch the order it is always only Article_1.pdf that works and none of the other. However there is nothing special about this article, it is not the longest nor the shortest, it doesn't have the largest/smallest number of figures, it doesn't have the largest/smallset size. I also tried specifying a given page, using instead of pages=-, pages={1} but I am getting the same error. I even tried using \shorthandoff{-} before calling includepdf but it doesn't work. I don't even know how to debug the issue as latex doesn't tell me anything else other than it can't find the file, which obviously is there. Can someone help me fix this issue? Thank you!

are you sure the file is there (and readable) can you show the log and the output from ls -l (or dir if windows)

Welcome to TeX.SE!

You can try to copy the filename directly from your file explorer to your tex source, to see if it works.

Some more things to try that might give you more information: use \includegraphics[page=1]{Article_1_SM} or just \includegraphics{Article_1_SM} to see if that works and/or if you get a different error. Rename the file (in the file explorer or terminal) to something simple, like hello.pdf, and try to include that. Try opening the file in a few different pdf viewers to see if it opens normally or if there are any issues with the file itself.

In the actual generated pdf file, I just end up with this line: width=!,height=!,pages=-,pagecommand=,width= instead of the actual pdf. In the log file I get this: l.20 ...{},width=\textwidth]{Article_1_SM.pdf}.
This error message was generated by an \errmessage
command, so I can't give any explicit help.
Pretend that you're Hercule Poirot: Examine all clues,
and deduce the truth by order and method.
